# Combine two fields of SOAP response to One in PARASOFT SOATest

Tags: rest, api, web-services, soap, assertions

I would like to combine two fields values of same SOAP response into One. So that I can assert the One filed of SOAP to REST response field.

SOAP Response:
Field 1 = date
Field 2 = Time

Combine SOAP field (1 &2) to Field 3.

Assert SOAP Field 3 to REST response field.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you found the answer on Parasoft's forum but to answer it here let me explain how you can achieve it:
If you extract values from message using XML DataBank you store them in writable column or variable ( or external data source).
Assuming that Field 1 = date and you assigned it to column or variable called date then you can use it later by calling variable/column name, in this case you should use it with special syntax: ${date}
The Field 2 = time assigned to column/variable time can be used with ${time}

Later you can use it and connect/join in following way: ${date}${time}